# Powershell switch statement not working with or-operator

Tags: powershell

Trying to get my switch statement working with an "-or" operater in it..
What am i doing wrong?

Code:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $a = 1031
PS C:\Windows\system32> switch ($a) {1031 {write "True"}}
True
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32>
PS C:\Windows\system32> switch ($a) {((1031) -or (2055)) {write "True"}}
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a scriptblock, `$_` is the value you're switching on (e.g $a):

```
switch ($a) 
{
    {$_ -eq 1031 -or $_ -eq 2055} {write "True"}
}
```